# How can I replace all special characters in a URL, using a Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying use regular expression to convert special characters in an url. Here's my sample code :

```
String formatUrl = "index.php?title=Test/enu/test/Tips_%26_Tricks/Tips_and_Tricks";
formatUrl = formatUrl.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]" , "-");
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert the special characters in the url such as ?_%. to "-" excluding "/".

The regular expression in my code converts everything resulting the output as

```
index-php-title-Test-enu-test-Tips--26-Tricks-Tips-and-Tricks
```

But I want it to be

```
index-php-title-Test/enu/test/Tips--26-Tricks/Tips-and-Tricks
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question shows that you did not understand the way a regular expression works ... I recommend reading a regular expression tutorial, to help you understanding why the answer works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
formatUrl = formatUrl.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9/]" , "-");
```

Answer (score 9):

You could just add your `/` into the regex:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9/]"
```

Comment: @PaulPRO ..thanks for your reply.Pls find my answer to hoipolloi. It'll explain why I'm not looking java encode/decode.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering what you're trying to achieve. Why not just decode the URL?

```
final String url = "index.php?title=Test/enu/test/Tips_%26_Tricks/Tips_and_Tricks";
final String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(decoded); // Prints index.php?title=Test/enu/test/Tips_&_Tricks/Tips_and_Tricks
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.My requirement is not about decoding an url, rather converting the control characters. This gets translated to a S3 key, which creates issues with ?= etc.I need to preserve the "/" to have it translate to a folder based structure in S3. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Shamik: Information like this should be in the question, not in a comment two pages down.

Comment: @Tim: Not necessarily. In the question, he stated exactly what he was trying to achieve. Why he was trying to achieve it really doesn't matter. I think hoipolloi was trying to out-guess the OP.